# Can Bremsstrahlung radiation produced as a result of electron-electron interaction?

Tags: nuclear-physics, x-rays

Can Bremsstrahlung radiation produced by the electron-electron interaction as e-e interaction can result acceleration due to coulomb repulsive force? If yes, how the energy of bremsstrahlung radiation produced by e-nucleus and e-e interaction can be compared?

Comment: This seems to be a fairly straight-forward problem, what seems to be your problem with the question(s)?

Comment: I wish to know the power of Bremsstrahlung radiation produce by e-e interaction.

Comment: Yes, your question is quite clear. My question is what have you tried and what don't you understand?